# splat over JavaScript object (with new)?

Tags: javascript, arguments, argument-passing, ecmascript-5, splat

How do I splat across objects without using [ECMA6 features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)?

#### Attempt

```
function can(arg0, arg1) {
    return arg0 + arg1;
}

function foo(bar, haz) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.haz = haz;
}

myArgs = [1,2];
```

With `can` I can just do:

```
can.apply(this, myArgs);
```

When trying with `foo`:

```
new foo.apply(this, myArgs);
```

I get this error (because I'm calling `new`):

```
TypeError: function apply() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using `Object.create`

```
function foo(bar, haz) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.haz = haz;
}

x = Object.create(foo.prototype);
myArgs = [5,6];
foo.apply(x, myArgs);

console.log(x.bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.create(proto)` is the right way to go about this.

Coco and LiveScript (Coffeescript subsets) offer a workaround:

```
new foo ...args
```

compiles to

```
(function(func, args, ctor) {
  ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
  var child = new ctor, result = func.apply(child, args), t;
  return (t = typeof result)  == "object" || t == "function" ? result || child : child;
  })
(foo, args, function(){});
```

And in CoffeeScript:

```
(function(func, args, ctor) {
  ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
  var child = new ctor, result = func.apply(child, args);
  return Object(result) === result ? result : child;
})(foo, args, function(){});
```

These hacks are ugly, slow, and imperfect; for example, `Date` relies on its internal `[[PrimitiveValue]]`. See [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2183).